# surge voltage characteristics of ceramic capacitors

Tags: capacitor, surge-protection, transient, ceramic, derating

I am reading a datasheet from Murata for a ceramic capacitor. According to the [datasheet](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/capacitor/mlcc/c02e.ashx):

> When AC voltage or pulse voltage is applied, the
>   peak-to-peak voltage shall not exceed the rated
>   DC voltage.

I have googled a little and could not find any ceramic capacitor datasheet with surge characteristics. My question is that for example if I have a 25V-rated ceramic capacitor, how much transient over-voltage (with determined duration) can I apply to this capacitor, is there any method or estimation to find this maximum? Does applying over-voltage transients cause degradation of the capacitor and other undesirable effects?
Many thanks for reading this question.

Comment: You answered your own question with that quote. After reading the datasheet say "Do not exceed this voltage", you come here asking, "Can I exceed this voltage?"

Comment: The datasheet already answered your question. What about it is unclear?

Comment: That data sheet has surge characteristics and a surge test circuit.

Comment: I am testing with a 16V ceramic capacitor, The capacitor is working with 24V and 100 ms duration pulse without any problem.

Comment: @user15847 Until you test a thousand capacitors for many hours that doesn't mean much. Manufacturers can't give a rating that is only true some of the time.

Comment: @user15847 the maximum values in datasheets are the values that the manufacturer can guarantee the part will work as specified. You may find some can work beyond the specs, some not. They won't all be *exactly* the same. You may try with another and find it does not work. You may have 1 in 100. This is why datasheets have maximum values. If you want your part to work reliably, **do not exceed them**

Comment: Why when I can work with over-voltaged transient pulses, they should limit voltages to the rated DC val\lue?

Comment: Because cumulative damage and accelerated failure. If you measure the lifetime of the component it will be less and you might even be able to measure changes in capacitor characteristics.

Comment: I have applied the pulse for 50 cycles. Anyway, you are right. The device would not be reliable. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Datasheet has pictures just under these statements, and you can see what these statements mean exactly.

[image]

> how much over-voltage can I apply to this capacitor, is there any method or estimation to find this maximum?

Maximum is a rated voltage.

> Does applying over-voltage transients cause degradation of the capacitor and other undesirable effects?

After this reliable operation may not be guaranteed. You can see in "test methods" chapter that Murata exceeds rated voltage during tests, but these are tests and not normal operating conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please give the page number? I could not find it. Thanks.

Comment: Search for "rated DC voltage" phrase in the document and you will find these all.

Comment: This is not a criticism of the answer but an observation. In the picture showing the AC voltage waveform surely "E" should be "2E"? Or "E" should be from the o volt position to one of the sinewave peaks?

Comment: @Andyaka I think E is just an absolute value of the voltage difference - maximum minus minimum. Just recalled that ceramic cap voltage must be derated, and it is important piece of info when talking about their voltage rating property.